# What are the other "home" screens called?

Tags: user-interface, accessibility, talk-back

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII when I get past the lock screen there are several "home" screens, each indicated by a clickable dash, and one of these (the second one on my device) has a home icon in place of the dash and can also be accessed by two (if an app is open) or one (if no app is open) clicks of the home button. Of course one can also swipe left and right from one screen to another (or use the dashes area as a scrollbar).

**Now my question**: if I were to write about these "home screens" differentiating between the "main home screen" and the other "secondary home screens", so as to differentiate between these two kinds of "home screen", is this the *corrrct terminology* or would I call these two different kind of screens something else?

Note: I am also but not exclusively asking this question with accessibility (TalkBack) in mind. Haven't figured out how to pass from one of these screens to the next with TalkBack enabled. (when an app is closed and the launcher is shown, no matter which page, TalkBack says "home screen").

Comment: Well, from the comment below it seems like they are all pages. TalkBack seems to call any of them home screen.

Comment: @JackMaddington: see my edit.

Comment: I guess there's no standard term announced by Google, though I'd tend to say "page" for its similar behaviour of [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) (from developer POV)

Comment: The Linux [Fvwm](http://fvwm.org) window manager also had something called FvwmPager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From source code of [Launcher3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/android-6.0.1_r16/src/com/android/launcher3/Workspace.java#83) in Android 6.0.1 r16:

> The workspace is a wide area with a wallpaper and a finite number of pages. Each page contains a number of icons, folders or widgets the user can interact with.

Honestly, this is the first time I heard the term *workspace* in context of a launcher for Android, but if you want a standard term, there you have it.

The page with home icon is referred as *default page* and the page currently displayed to the user is called *current page*. This is what I understood from [this line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/android-6.0.1_r16/src/com/android/launcher3/Workspace.java#590) in the source code of the said launcher.

**Edit:** After checking the sample of [Home](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-6.0.1_r16/samples/Home/) app in Android 6.0.1 r16 (they are using a very old sample for developers), I noticed [this line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Home/src/com/example/android/home/Home.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F#162) *inter alia* and I conclude that each page can be referred to as home screen and you can reference another page by calling it previous, succeeding, or preceding home screen or by using the numbers available through scroll, such as *home screen 3*.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would call all other screens as *pages*, while the default screen that appears when you tap the *home* button as *home screen* as Firelord's answer also suggests

Samsung seems to think otherwise ! On page 39 of user manual downloaded from https://www.att.com/support_static_files/manuals/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III.pdf, it says

> Your phone comes with seven home screens. You can arrange them in any preference you want

It makes sense to stick with generally understood terminology and use *default home screen* and *pages*