# Is there a glossary of Android's UI elements

Tags: user-interface

Often, when I'm looking for the solution to some problem I'm having on my phone, the hardest part is knowing what to call the specific menu, or piece of the UI, causing the issue.

Is there an official (or non official but accepted) glossary of the different UI elements?

Comment: Something like [Popups, dialogs, notifications, toasts: what's the difference?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/52789/16575)

Comment: Something like that, yes, but with things like status bar, notification bar/panel, etc.

Comment: OK, to make that "central stuff" easier to find I've initiated the [tag-wiki for `user-interface`](/tags/user-interface/info) :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if an *official* glossary exists, but information below is in line with what is generally used.

Be aware that the same thing may be referred differently causing confusion - for instance , what you use to access menu in an app or browser is called *3 dot(s) menu* or *overflow menu* (official name):

[image: overflow menu]

- [Hamburger menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) only refers to those displayed as 3 horizontal lines and expands to show a side panel when clicked on - different from the 3 dots which does what the MENU hardware key does -This icon is on the left hand side of screen (thanks to Izzy and Andy Yan)

[image]

- From [Beginner's guide to Android - How to use Android's home screens](http://www.beginandroid.com/homescreen.shtml). These pictures pertain to Android Version 4 and latter Android versions have incorporated changes and additions but the essentials are same - a status bar is still the same, but the symbols have changed, same with navigation bar

[image]
[image]

- **Notifications and Status**

[image]

- From my device

  **Notification tray**

[image]

**Quick Settings** (Varies from device to device and modifications by user )

[image]

- Also see [Popups, dialogs, notifications, toasts: what's the difference?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/52789/131553) and [What are the other "home" screens called?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/136184/131553)